# React Native WebView pre-render for faster performance - how to do it?

Tags: webview, react-native

In React Native, when using the WebView component, it starts to load the external content at the moment when the component will be rendered.

To increase performance in the application, I have tried to pre-fetch the external HTML so that it is ready when the component will be rendered. It seems like it is only an actual call to the render method will cause the loading to start and this is only controlled by what is rendered on the screen. I suppose React Native has no concept of shadow DOM that could be used to call the render method a head of time. 
Trying to manipulate the lifecycle methods does also not work and is probably not a correct way of doing it either?

I have also tried to do a `fetch()` of the external HTML-content, with the right user-agent in the header, and pass the responseText to the WebComponent. This sometimes works for some sites of sources, but for others i run into ACAP (Automated Content Access Protocol) issues, to this is not the preferred solution.

Is there a way to pre-fetch external HTML content to a WebView component so that it displays faster?

Comment: I am also looking for any solution related to this query.

Answer (score 11):

`fetch` method runs on react side, `fetch` keep cache but that available for react apis and there component. `WebView` has there own caching concept. It's a browser. Caching of `fetch` will not avaialble for `WebView`. For faster loading by pre loaded data, You should fetch data by `WebView` instance of `fetch` api.

You can create a hidden `WebView` by setting width and height `0` and load your site on that. This will load your site on `ViewView` and keep cache, that will available for next time loading.

### Here is a sample

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  WebView,
  Alert,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';

// const url = 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'
// const url = 'https://in.yahoo.com/?p=us'
const url = 'https://www.facebook.com/'

class TestWebView extends Component {
  render() {
    var renderTime = Date.now();

    return (
      <WebView
        source={{uri: url}}
        style={{marginTop: 20, flex: 1}}
        onLoad={() => {
          Alert.alert('On load event', `Loading time : ${Date.now() - renderTime}`)
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      isLoaded: false,
    }
  }

  render() {

    if (this.state.isLoaded) {
      return (
        <TestWebView />
      )
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{height: 0, width: 0}}>
          <WebView
            source={{uri: url}}
            onLoad={() => {
              this.setState({isLoaded: true})
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <ActivityIndicator />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
});
```

I test this. After first time loaded data on `WebView`, It reduce 70% loading on actual `WebView` where we want to show to user.

Comment: The idea of setting height dynamically solve my problem too. Thanks!